# CSS 3 Animation

Tags: css, animation, svg, html5-canvas

I am trying to move a bar to follow the path of complete square box animation . But i got stuck how to make transform on following right direction  multiple animation in css3 .

once the bar travels from left to right then the bar should transform rotate 90 deg and then top to bottom animation should start after that delay of left to right let's say 15s.

```css
#overlay{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #000;
}
.main-box{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: none;
  border:30px solid #fff;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin:  auto;
}
.loader-bar{
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #ea2330;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: -30px;
  animation: leftmove 5s linear infinite;
   
}

@-webkit-keyframes leftmove {
  0% {left: 0px;}
  25% {left: 80px;}
}

@keyframes leftmove {
  0% {left: 0px;}
  25% {left: 80px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes topmove {
  50% {transform: rotate(90deg);}
  70% {right: 380px;}
}

@keyframes topmove {
  50% {transform: rotate(90deg);}
  75% {right: 380px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  <div class="main-box">
    <div class="loader-bar">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check my codepen.

https://codepen.io/azharuddin540/pen/bvRaeG

Comment: you should look into SVG line animation - https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

Comment: check my pen  to see the output https://codepen.io/Divine1/pen/zWPERR

Comment: Thanks @-divine . you are rock.

Comment: Please check my pin when iam trying to add infinite iteration count that time it is giving problem.

Please Divine check this out if possible.